# How to store subarrays of different size into a single 2d array

Tags: java

I’m trying to store 1d array of different size into a 2d array and then sort the 2d array based on the sum of subarray.

Comment: OK. How do you want to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int[][] arrays = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7},};
int[][] sorted = Arrays.stream(arrays)
    .map(a -> new Object() {
        int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();
        int[] array = a;
    })
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.sum))
    .map(obj -> obj.array)
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sorted));
```

output

```
[[4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [7], [5, 6]]
```